# How to replace this OR conditional

Tags: mysql

I have the following simplified query:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (a < 1000 AND a > c) 
    OR (a = 0 AND b > c)
```

Now this table is *massive* with a bunch of other little conditionals going on, so I'd like to remove the OR conditional here, hopefully without needing to do a `join`.

I've been looking at whether `IF` blocks are possible in a `WHERE` clause, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: I'm smelling a possible [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I reject the premise of the question. What does table size have to do with the inclusion or otherwise of conditions

Comment: Looked at subqueries already? I don't see the rest of the query, so wondering if it could help you, but it's just an idea\

Comment: I think you can use UNION:
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
  FROM table t1
 WHERE t1.a < 1000
UNION
SELECT t2.a, t2.b,t2.c 
  FROM table t2 
 WHERE t2.a = 0 AND t2.b > t2.c